# Ubuntu Server not rebooting but will power off

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have 2 identical servers running Ubuntu 9.10 and I've been playing with Ubuntu's upstart system, trying to write a sort-of complex boot order for a few services.

I've also played with init scripts to try and achieve the required effect, but I've now removed all my initscripts.

I've been doing this only on one server.  Part way through my development of my upstart scripts, I noticed that the server wasn't rebooting properly - it kills off rsyslog-kmsg then just sits there.  If you run the reboot command again, it reboots.

I removed all traces of the scripts I created and still it won't reboot, so I'm now thinking of done something but I cannot work out what I've done that I haven't reversed.

The other server is perfectly fine.  I've compared the timestamp of the upstart scripts (in /etc/init) and copied over the init.d, rc[0-6].d directory contents onto the first server, but it still won't reboot.

The strange thing is, if you do halt instead of reboot, it powers off as normal - it just won't reboot.

There are no messages in dmesg or /var/log/messages after the boot process completes.

Any ideas?  I'd prefer not to have to re-install the OS as it's a remotely-hosted server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a follow-up, I found the Ubuntu net installer, so it was a lot quicker to re-install the OS.